# String class make confusion

Tags: java, string, keyword

Recently I just got an error in java that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Even if my class was just of 3 line of code.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I was wondering why this happens, but later on i get to know there was a public class String which i had tried & created in same package.

so now new question arise is what happen in this kind of situation though String is not a `keyword` defined in java (you can use in your code)

Then I just deleted String.java & String.class file from the package but it sounds odd that you could not use String class as well.

Question: Does java gives major priority to our custom class?

Comment: i really don't get what you are tryin to do

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your main method needs to match

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[] args){ ... }
```

If you create your own `String` class in the same package where the class with your main method is, it will become

```
 public static void main(your.own.package.String[] args){ ... }
```

which is valid, but will not allow the runtime launcher to find a main method anymore, since it expects `java.lang.String[]` as parameter.

The classes from `java.lang` are imported automatically by default, so you don't need an explicit `import` statement - that probably made it even more confusing to you.

As a rule of thumb, I would avoid to name my own classes the same as classes from the Java Runtime, whenever possible - especially from `java.lang`.

See also the [JLS: Chapter 7. Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5):

> A package consists of a number of compilation units (§7.3). A compilation unit **automatically has access to all types declared in its package** and also **automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang**.

Comment: but that means if i write String[] that means my coustom class?
Does it really mean that?

Comment: but if I have 2 imported class with same how java compiler judge which is to be take & which is not to be take?(not in class path but othr package)

Comment: If you write String[], then the compiler looks at the imports to check if there is an import for String. Since your other class String lies in the same package it was imported by default.

Comment: Any reference for this? I not arguing that this is wrong, but `java.lang` is imported by default (as written in answer)... And JRE jars are first on classpath AFAIK...

Comment: Thanks for reference that current package is imported by default, but still wondering why compiler is not complaining about ambiguous class name...

Comment: Good question, and I also did not yet find an authoritative answer on the **order** of the imports ...

Comment: I did one more test, not sure if sufficient, to have String in another package and use import another.package.* and still the one from same package had priority. When there is String only in another package (not in the same one) and it is imported as another.package.* I'm getting ambiguous error...

Comment: **authoritative answer** do you mean by that by oracle?

Comment: @Betlista please edit & add your test in question as well. so that we can get more clear & batter answer.

Comment: No, I had the new idea just now, when I import java.lang.String explicitly, it works = you can run the `main()` (be aware that Eclipse for example removes such import when `organize imports` command is invoked).

Comment: @Betlista The interesting thing though is that the types from the current package always seem to have priority over any imported ones - and that no Error is emitted by the compiler then ...  I have posted a followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477783/order-of-automatically-imported-packages-and-ambiguity

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a fully qualified name:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) ...
```

The story you are telling says that we can use `String` as the name for one of our classes. But, like in real life, if there are two people named "John" around, you sometimes need to disambiguate them.

Comment: of cource there can be.. like kite(bird,paper thing.)