# Order of automatically imported packages and ambiguity

Tags: java, import, jls

[JLS: Chapter 7. Packages:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5)

> A package consists of a number of compilation units (§7.3). A compilation unit **automatically has access to all types declared in its package** and also **automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang**.

Lets assume the following code:

```
package com.example.p1;
public class MyClass { }
```

```
package com.example;
public class MyClass { }
```

```
package com.example;
public class String { }
```

```
package com.example;

import com.example.p1.*;

public class MainNameClash {
   private String s;    // No Error, even though ambiguous with java.lang.String!
   private MyClass m;   // No error, even though ambiguous with com.example.p1.MyClass!
}
```

If I move `MyClass` from `com.example` into `com.example.p2` and import it with `import com.example.p2.*`, I get `Error: the type MyClass is ambigious` at the place where it is used.

It seems that the Types from the package itself always have precedence over any other imported types, be it automatically from `java.lang` or be it explicitly with a wildcard import, and that the compiler does not emit any warning or error.

Question:

- Why does the java compiler not emit an ambiguity error in this case?
- Where in the JLS is this behavior defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The import statements of the form:

```
import packageName.subPackage.*
```

is [Type-Import-on-Demand Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2). i.e, the classes or any types from them will be imported only when that type is not available in the scope of current compilation unit.

From example *7.5.2-1* of that JLS section only:

> The declaration might be shadowed by a single-type-import declaration of a type whose simple name is Vector; *by a type named Vector and declared in the package to which the compilation unit belongs*; or any nested classes or interfaces.

So, if you have a class `String` in the same package as your class, then using `String` in that class, will refer to your class, as `java.lang.String` will not be imported. It will only be imported on **demand**, as shown in [example 6.4.1-2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#d5e7173) of [JLS § 6.4.1 - Shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is covered in [Shadowing & Obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4) in that a package scoped Class takes precedence over a wildcard import.

Comment: I've been struggling with interpreting those docs... it seems clear that both package-scoped and wildcard (type-import-on-demand) can not shadow any other declaration, but I can't find the wording that says which of these take precedence over the other. Furthermore, I can't find anything that says how the implicit type-import-on-demand for `java.lang.*` is applied. I'm curious to know which takes priority between implicit `java.lang.*` and `samepackage.*`, and any explicit `package.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is about *simple type names*:

> [6.5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html) **Simple Type Names** If a type name consists of a single Identifier, then the identifier must occur in the scope of exactly one
>   visible declaration of a type with this

About *scope* we can read here:

> ([6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)) The scope of a declaration is the region of the program within which
>   the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a
>   simple name, provided it is visible

..

> The scope of a type imported by a single-type-import declaration
>   (§7.5.1) or a type-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.2) is all the
>   class and interface type declarations (§7.6) in the compilation unit
>   in which the import declaration appears, as well as any annotations on
>   the package declaration (if any) of the compilation unit .