# Can we access built-in classes without import statement

Tags: java

I had created a class `Exception` (knowing that there already exists a built-in subclass with the same name) as follows :

```
class Exception {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        int i=8;
        try{
            int a = args.length;
            int g = i/a;
        } catch(ArithemticException e){
            System.out.println("here is the error:"+e);
        }
    }
}


class Except7 {
    static int h;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            int h = 9 / 0;
            System.out.println("//");
        } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            h = 4;
            System.out.println(h);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("h");
        }
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed that I have written wrong spelling of 'Arithmetic' in the former code, so certainly enough  the compiler showed an error that it cannot find this symbol(`ArithemticException e`). 
What I did was that instead of changing the spelling here, I wrote another code (the latter one). Here, I wrote correct spelling of Arithmetic and tried compiling it. It gave me two errors :

1. `incompatible types (required : Throwable     found: Exception )`
2. `cannot find symbol(ArithemticException.java)`

**My doubts are:**

1. How can we so easily change a built-in class (of Exception) ?Is it because it is an abstract class ?
2. And even if I have an access to it directly(i.e. without using an 'import' statement), I didn't  tend to change the name of exception (ArithemticException). I had simply put it in a 'catch' statement. Then, why do other programs which don't have an 'import' statement  are able to access it.
   (I did not create any packages also, to say that they were package protected)
3. The previous program did not get compiled and still other programs come up with the error of 'cannot find symbol' .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can we so easily change a built-in class (of Exception)

You can not.

What happens is that your own class `Exception` is imported without any explicit import statement, because it is in the same package as `Except7`. Hence, when compiling `Except7`, the compiler uses `yourPackage.Exception`, not `java.lang.Exception`.

See also the [JLS: Chapter 7. Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5):

> A package consists of a number of compilation units (§7.3). A compilation unit **automatically has access to all types declared in its package** and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang.

See also [String class make confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476504/string-class-make-confusion)

Comment: O.K. ! So, it goes to my current directory which behaves like a default package for all my programs I am saving there.

Comment: Yes (precisely, "package", not "directory"). On a side note, do not use the default package - always put your classes in a concrete package.

Comment: So, actually shadowing was taking place !